# node.js application - integrate mongodb in appfog

Tags: node.js, mongodb, appfog

I am starting to use appfog services in order to host node application.
I am getting trouble trying to use mongodb in my application.
In you tutorial here: https://docs.appfog.com/services/mongodb#walkthrough it is written to connect mongodb like this:

```
require('mongodb').connect(mongourl, ...
```

while mogourl is the url generated by the `generate_mongo_url` function.
The problem is that I am using newer api (I think) and I cannot pass url to the open method. This is how I am using mongodb:

```
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server('localhost', 27017));
mongoClient.open(function(err, mongoClient) { ...
```

Where and how can I use the generated mongourl? How can I pass the credentials and the mongo variable used in generate_mongo_url function?

**UPDATE**
According to @mjhm suggestion, this is my open function:

```
var mongoService = null;
if(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES){
    var env = JSON.parse(process.env.VCAP_SERVICES);
    mongoService = env["mongodb-1.8"][0]["credentials"];
} else {
    mongoService = {
        "hostname": "localhost",
        "port": 27017,
        "isLocal": true,
        "username": "",
        "password": "",
        "name": ""
    };
}

this.mongoClient.open(function(err, mongoClient) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("Open DB Success");
        var db = mongoClient.db(DB_NAME);

        if (!mongoService.isLocal) {
            db.authenticate(mongoService.username,
                mongoService.password, function (err, result) {
                    if (!err) {
                        console.log("Authenticate DB Success");
                        doAction();
                    } else {
                        console.log("Authenticate DB Error: " + err);
                    }
            });
        } else {
            doAction();
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Open DB Error: " + err);
    }
});
```

When I am running this code on appfog, I am waiting a lot of time (more then 20 seconds) and then I get:

```
$ curl myappname.eu01.aws.af.cm/list
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the MongoClient.connect function

http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#mongoclient-connect

It takes the url you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

the URL where your client / driver wants to connect to was 'localhost'. I replaced it with a 
variable *mongoUrl*

```
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server(mongoUrl, 27017));
```

Comment: Then I get: Open DB Error: Error: failed to connect to [mongodb://my_user_name:my_password@localhost:27017/db_name:27017]

Answer (score 0):

You need to [authenticate](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#authenticate) after opening the database.  The way to think of it is that authentication happens against the database not the connection, so as you discovered the `generate_mongo_url` function isn't very useful.

For example:

```
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server('localhost', 27017));

mongoClient.open(function(err, mongoClient) {
    var db = mongoClient.db('test');
    db.authenticate('me', 'mypwd', function (err, result) {
        var coll = db.collection('query_example3');
        coll.find().toArray(function(err, result) {
            console.log(result);
            process.exit(0);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please see question update. I used your code but the application doesn't running on server. Any idea?

Comment: I don't know where appfog is writing its console.log messages, but you might find info there.  Also you might try adapting their "Hello World" application as closely as possible with the MongoClient mechanism.